# VB.NET Validating Checkboxes

Tags: vb.net, checkbox

how do i check a single checkbox if multiple checkboxes are checked, i.e. i have 51 checkboxes and if that 50 are checked that single remaining checkbox will be checked. how do i do that?

this is my code:

```
For Each chk In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf chk Is CheckBox Then
        If CType(chk, CheckBox).Checked = True Then
                chkAll.Checked = True
        End If
    End If
Next
```

If this is correct then my problem is i don't know where to put this. Because it should not be in a `Button`.

Comment: Is it OK if you have LINQ solution?

Comment: It's okay, It's for someone who knows how to use LINQ, because i don't =)

Comment: OK, posted a LINQ version answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set this as the handler for all your CheckBoxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged ' And so on...
    Dim allChecked As Boolean = True

    For Each chk In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf chk Is CheckBox Then
            If chk.Equals(chkAll) Then
                Continue For
            End If

            If CType(chk, CheckBox).Checked = False Then
                allChecked = False

                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    chkAll.Checked = allChecked
End Sub
```

Comment: Where should i put this? In `chkAll_CheckedChanged`? It's not working, i can't uncheck the `chkAll` checkbox control.

Comment: I didn't know that was possible! Thanks!

Comment: If `chkAll` control is in then `Me.Controls` collection (I assumed  it is), then this solution will not work, because `chkAll.Checked` is always false

Comment: You can check whether `chk` is `chkAll` and then ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Create function which check all CheckBoxes

```
Public Function IsAllCheckBoxesChecked() As Boolean
    Dim isAllChecked As Boolean = True
    For Each chk As CheckBox In Me.Controls.Cast(Of CheckBox)
        If checkbox.Equals(Me.chkAll) = True Then Continue For
        If checkBox.Checked = false Then
            isAllChecked = false
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Return isAllChecked
End Function
```

Or LINQ approach

```
Public Function IsAllCheckBoxesChecked() As Boolean
    Return Me.Controls.
              Cast(Of CheckBox).
              All(Function(chk) chk.Equals(Me.chkAll) = False AndAlso chk.Checked = True)
End Function
```

Then create CheckedChange eventhandler for all checkboxes and use those functions there

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)
    If chk.Checked = True Then
        ' Check if all CheckBoxes are checked
        Me.chkAll.Checked = IsAllCheckBoxesChecked()
    Else
        ' No need to loop other chekboxes, anyway it is false
        Me.chkAll.Checked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, prepare your `CheckedChanged` event handler for all your checkboxes:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged, CheckBox2.CheckedChanged, CheckBox3.CheckedChanged, CheckBox4.CheckedChanged 'etc..
    .
    .
    .
End Sub
```

Then in your event handler, use LINQ `Where` and `Select` to solve your problem best:

```
Dim allCheckBoxes = Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is CheckBox).Select(Function(y) CType(y, CheckBox))
Dim thisCb = CType(sender, CheckBox)
If allCheckBoxes.Where(Function(x) x.Checked).ToList().Count >= 50 And thisCb.Checked Then 'if atleast 50 checkboxes are checked and the current one is checked
    Dim nonCheckedCheckBoxes = allCheckBoxes.Where(Function(t) Not t.Checked).ToList()
    nonCheckedCheckBoxes.ForEach(Function(t) t.Checked = True)
End If
```

What the LINQ above does is basically to get all the `CheckBoxes` lazily:

```
Dim allCheckBoxes = Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)().Where(Function(x) TypeOf x Is CheckBox).Select(Function(y) CType(y, CheckBox))
```

Then, to check if the number of checked `CheckBoxes` are equal to 50 and the sender's (`CheckBox`) is checked. If the sender is not checked, then we omit it because it could be the user's intention to uncheck it (correction credited to [Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1565525/fabio)):

```
If allCheckBoxes.Where(Function(x) x.Checked).ToList().Count = 50 And thisCb.Checked Then 'if 50 checkboxes are checked
```

If it does, then you check the remaining non-checked `CheckBoxes`:

```
Dim nonCheckedCheckBoxes = allCheckBoxes.Where(Function(t) Not t.Checked).ToList()
nonCheckedCheckBoxes.ForEach(Function(t) t.Checked = True)
```

Comment: With this approach, if all checkboxes(51) are checked, then user will not be able to uncheck any other checkbox. When user uncheck some, then your code will count that at this moment checked collection contain 50 checkboxes and will automatically check just unchecked checkbox back